# Windows 7 minimize, maximize, close button styles

Tags: windows-7

This is more out of curiosity, something I noticed recently that I don't know why it's happening.  Are there different windows border button styles in Windows 7?  I.e., the minimize, maximize, and close button styles?

I have a Windows 7 Professional machine at work and those button styles are each the same size rectangle, with rounded corners, with a small gap between each button.

I was reinstalling Windows 7 Pro at home this weekend and realized on there those same buttons are what I think of as the "Vista" style, and what I see in most Windows 7 screenshots.  The "close" button is wider, and all three are flush against each other.

I can try and get screenshots to post later if that helps.  Is this a difference between effects being on, or Aero or something?  I can't find which settings might affect it and I'm stumped.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably Aero vs. Aero Basic - see the first two screenshots [here](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20081029/windows-7-themes-glass-basic-and-classic/).

Comment: Ahhh, that's exactly it!  I was apparently having trouble with my image search keywords.  Thanks!